# Рекурсивная функция с указателями

Tags: c, массивы, функции, указатели, рекурсия

Вызываю функцию из главной программы и передаю значения аргументов по ссылке , но функция потом рекурсивно вызывает сама себя , что делать с указателями ?Как они себя поведут .Например , я веду счетчик перемещений в быстрой сортировке

Из главной программы вызываю так

```
             qsortx(A,0,N-1, &movents, &compasion);
```

Формальные аргументы в шапке функции выглядят так :

```
               void qsortx(int *a, int low,int  high,int *movents,int *compasion) {
```

А в рекурсивных вызовах этой самой функции так :

```
             qsortx(a, i, high,movents,compasion);
```

Но переменные перемещений и сравнений остаются равны нулю , где ошибка ?
Целиком функция выглядит так :

```
void qsortx(int *a, int low,int  high,int *movents,int *compasion) {
    int i=0, j=0;
    int tmp=0, medianofthree=0;

    i = low;
    j = high;
    int k = 0, l = 0, m = 0;
    k = *(a + 0);
    l = *(a + high);
    m = *(a + (high + low) / 2);
    /*Median-of-three*/
    if (k > l && k < m || k < l && k > m)
        medianofthree= k;
    else
        if (l > k && l < m || l < k && l > m)
            medianofthree=l;
        else
            medianofthree= m;
    /*Median-of-three*/
    printf("\n%d\n", medianofthree);
    do {
        while (a[i] < medianofthree) 
        {
            i++;
            compasion++;
        }
        while (a[j] > medianofthree)
        {
            j--;
            compasion++;
        }
        if (i <= j)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[j])
            {
                tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = tmp;
            }
            i++;
            if (j > 0)
            {
                j--;
            }
        }
    } while (i <= j);

    if (i < high)
    {
        qsortx(a, i, high,movents,compasion);
    }
    if (j > low)
    {
        qsortx(a, low, j,movents, compasion);
    }
}
```

Comment: Код, как используете `movments` и `compasion` приведите

Comment: Например так  while (a[j] > medianofthree)
   {
    j--;
    compasion++;
   }

Comment: `comparision++;` -- это вы указатель двигаете. Вам надо `(*comparision)++;`

Comment: @avp,а с рекурсивными вызовами всё в порядке ?